# If I use gitlab-ci for my private repository does it remain private?

Tags: security, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, privacy

So, I have a private library that I am building, I plan on publishing it after I get my research paper published and the work is in the alpha stage. I need to keep the algorithm private and so I am working on a private repository in "Gitlab.com". Now, I have seen that we can use "gitlab-ci" even for private repositories but I am having trouble understanding the "shared runners" concept.

what I think is that these runners run our code with other code with a similar configuration in a queue. I am not sure if that is completely correct.

Is my code still private when I use "gitlab-ci" with a private repository in "Gitlab.com"? or can it be accessed somewhere/somehow publicly?

I have this private repository in Gitlab.com it is not Gitlab enterprise edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: No, your code will not be accessible publicly.

Gitlab runner clones your repo using an access token and then runs the ci steps. 
If you build using docker images, your code will be completely cleaned up when the ci steps are complete. Because the docker container will be cleaned up immediately.

If you use normal runner, gitlab runner does cache your code, but I don't think that is a concern, because there is no public access to these caches.